# Why its <@&undefined>?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So basically when i doing /update with my bot its working its adding the roles but in the message its says <@&undefined> again its adding the user roles.

Part of the code:

```
 const addedRoles = [];
const removedRoles = [];

try {
  const inGroup = await noblox.getRankInGroup(groupid, await noblox.getIdFromUsername(robloxUsername));
  if (inGroup) {
    // Find the matching rankbind
    const rankNumber = await noblox.getRankInGroup(groupid, await noblox.getIdFromUsername(robloxUsername));
    const rankbind = groups.rankbinds.find(r => r.rank === rankNumber);


    
    if (rankbind) {
      const rolesArray = rankbind.roles;

  // Add all roles that are in the rolesArray
  const rolesToAdd = rolesArray.filter(roleId => !guildMember.roles.cache.has(roleId));
  if (rolesToAdd.length > 0) {
    await guildMember.roles.add(rolesToAdd);
    addedRoles.push(...rolesToAdd);
  }
    
  // Remove all roles that are not in the rolesArray, 
  const rolesToRemove = guildMember.roles.cache.filter(role => !rolesArray.includes(role.id) && role.id !== guild.id);
  if (rolesToRemove.size > 0) {
    await guildMember.roles.remove(rolesToRemove);
    removedRoles.push(...rolesToRemove);
  }


      // Set the user's nickname
      const template = rankbind.template;
      const nickname = `${template} ${robloxUsername}`;
      if (nickname !== guildMember.nickname) {
        await guildMember.setNickname(nickname);
      }
    }
  }


  // Send confirmation message
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('#000000')
    .setAuthor({
      name: guildMember.user.tag,
      iconURL: guildMember.user.displayAvatarURL(),
    })
    .setTitle('Roles Update')
    .setDescription('Successfully updated user roles')
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Nickname', value: guildMember.nickname || guildMember.user.username },
      {
        name: 'Roles Added',
        value: addedRoles.length ? addedRoles.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join('\n') : 'None'
      },
      {
        name: 'Roles Removed',
        value: removedRoles.length ? removedRoles.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`).join('\n') : 'None'
      },
    );
```

Message picture:
[Picture][1]

I'm using discord js. Node.js v18.15.0. no idea if this information will help you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0CnE.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when storing the roles, you are not storing a role object, but a roleId, so the array addedRoles is an array of ids, which is why it returns undefined.

try replacing
`` addedRoles.map(role => `<@&${role.id}>`) ``

with `` addedRoles.map(roleId => `<@&${roleId}>`) ``